# Matching similar sets of numbers using linear least squares?

Tags: sql

Consider if you have two sets of numbers:

SetA:

```
10
20
30
40
```

And another larger set of numbers:

SetB:

```
15
20
35
40
50
```

The goal is to eliminate the items from the larger of the two sets, such that there are the same number of items in both sets, and you are left with sets that are as "close" as possible.  I got the idea that I could try all pairs of each item and minimize the square of the differences.  For example, I think the solution to the above would be:

```
SetA  SetB   Diff  DiffSquared
10    15     5     25
20    20     0     0 
30    35     5     25
40    40     0     0

DiffSquaredSum == 50
```

It is the solution because that is the combination that will give you the smallest DiffSquaredSum.  I don't really care about the pairing of items together, it is mainly about trimming the larger set down to a set that is the same number of items, and where the items are as close together as possible.  I realized I could use the concept of linear least squares to solve this, but I'm not sure where I would begin in terms of coding this.  I would prefer to use SQL but I am not concerned about generating an exact solution as getting an idea of a general approach so I can gauge how difficult this would be.

I think it would basically would involve trying all possible combinations of the two sets:

```
SetA  SetB   Diff  DiffSquared
10    15     5     25
20    20     0     0 
30    35     5     25
40    50     10    100

SetA  SetB   Diff  DiffSquared
10    15     5     25
20    20     0     0 
30    40     10    100
40    50     10    100
```

Etc. and then selecting the group with the minimum Sum of DiffSquared.  I might begin by generating a row_number for SetA, and then for SetB, and then joining on that, which happens to give the answer but that is only by coincidence:

```
Row#    SetA  SetB
1        10    15
2        20    20 
3        30    35
4        40    40 
5       NULL   50
```

To be sure I found the answer I would need to do this repeatedly somehow and have an ID that tells me which group is which so that I can do a group by on it and then look at each sum.  **I am not sure how to get this set though:**

```
Attempt#  Row#   SetA  SetB
1         1       10    15
1         2       20    20 
1         3       30    35
1         4       40    40 
2         1       10    15
2         2       20    20 
2         3       30    35
2         4       40    50 
3         1       10    15
3         2       20    20 
3         3       30    40
3         4       40    50 
etc....
```

Notice each attempt# I have eliminated a different item from SetB.  In actuality SetB might be many items larger than A, so there would be more items eliminated, and thus more possibilities.  Once I have the above, I would just add the field calculating the squared difference, and then do a sum with a group by on the attempt #.  Then I could select the Attempt# with the smallest SumDiffSquared.  I would probably need to store the intermediate results in a temp table or table variable so that I could then walk backwards from that ID to get the elements in the successful set.

So the problem is: How to generate all the permutations of those "attempts"?

Answer (score 1):

You could try taking everything from setB that has an exact match in setA (in your example, the 20 and 40,) then sum the remaining numbers in setA (10+30 = 40) and try to find the closest matching sum with the same number of operands (2, 10 and 30) in setB.
In your example, that would be 15+35 = 50.

I'm not sure why you're squaring the differences.

If you want all possible combinations of both sets, you use an outer join without an ON clause.

Comment: When I first learned about the squared difference, I thought the same thing.  The sum of squares is a concept of determining how close two sets of data are.  However, it is traditionally applied to fitting curves to data.  But basically the concept is if you had (1,12) and (6,7), then 1 and 6 have a diff of 5, and 12 and 7 have a diff of 5, so you could say the sum of the difference is 10, but the sum of squares is 50(25+25).  If you had (5,16) and (6,7), **the sum of the difference is also 10, but the sum of squares is much larger**, 81 = 1^2+9^2, and so is considered to be a worse "fit".

Comment: ok, if that's how the business defines closest 'fit,' then you have to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention dbms, so I used Oracle.

```
with crossjoined as(
  select b
        ,a
        ,abs(a-b) as diff
        ,row_number() over(partition by b order by abs(a-b), a) as rn
    from SetA cross join SetB
)
,ranked as(
  select b,a,diff, row_number() over(order by diff,a) as rn
    from crossjoined
   where rn = 1
)
select b
  from ranked
 where rn <= (select count(*) from SetA)
 order by b;
```

Let me explain how it works, and then you can decide if I understood your problem correctly. The query has three parts:

**Part 1. "crossjoined"**
Here I create all combinations of A and B. So using your sample data, B15 is paired with A10, A20, A30, A40 and so on. For each B, I rank all A by the difference. In case several A has the same difference (as A10 and A20 has for B15) I sort the lowest A first. A sample of this part of the query is shown below.

```
B    A  DIFF  RN
--   -- ----  --
15   10 5      1
15   20 5      2
15   30 15     3
15   40 25     4
20   20 0      1
20   10 10     2
20   30 10     3
20   40 20     4
```

**Part 2. "ranked"**
This part of the query basically picks the best A for each B. This is implemented by `where rn = 1`. The result will have one row for each original B. The rows will be sorted by the difference. In case two rows have the same difference, the row with smallest A will be sorted frst. Below is the full result of "crossjoined" and "ranked" given your sample data:

```
B    A  DIFF  RN
--   -- ----  --
20   20    0   1
40   40    0   2
15   10    5   3
35   30    5   4
50   40   10   5
```

**Part 3. "main query"** Now it's time to eliminate items in that set to the same number of items as in set A. Following your logic for finding the set with the smallest difference, I use the rank (rn) from "ranked" part and pick the first N rows. Where N is the number of items in A.

Let me know if I can explain anything in more detail.

Comment: Not sure that this is a requirement but does this ensure that each member of a set can only be used once? i.e. if SetA has `10,20` and SetB has `9,10` does your query return `10,10` and `10,9` - or does it return  `10,9` and `20,10`?

Comment: @Martin, it pairs both B with A10. So my query does not "consume" each A once used.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to make the smaller set larger, instead I want to make the larger set smaller, to match the number of units in the smallest of the two sets.  Which means eliminating items, not duplicating them.

Comment: @AaronLS, the result from my query contains the same number of rows  as the smallest set. But it may reuse the same A more than once, as Martin pointed out.